# Python PywinAuto : how to set file name in Open Dialog

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I want to automate task in my app using [PywinAuto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/) python lib. My goal is to click the open file button and load the file. I had managed to start app and open the file Open Dialog
however am unable to set filename to desire file path.

[image]

**my code**

```py
app = application.Application(backend="uia")
app.start(MyAppPath).connect(title="MyApp",timeout = 5)
app.MyApp.wait('visible')
# click the open button
app.MyApp.Open.click()
app.MyApp.Open.print_control_identifiers()
# Open Dailogue identifiers dump : https://pastebin.com/nt5MpQJx
# tried to set file name , but not worked
app.Open.child_window(title="File name:", control_type="Text").Edit.SetText('C:\myfile.txt')
```

so any idea how to set the file name.

Answer (score 1):

ok so i have fixed it by changing `control_type="Text"` to `control_type="ComboBox"`  thought it should be `Text` but its `ComboBox`

**working code**

```py
app = application.Application(backend="uia")
app.start(MyAppPath).connect(title="MyApp",timeout = 5)
app.MyApp.wait('visible')
# click the open button
app.MyApp.Open.click()
app.MyApp.Open.print_control_identifiers()
# Open Dailogue identifiers dump : https://pastebin.com/nt5MpQJx
# tried to set file name , but not worked
app.Open.child_window(title="File name:", control_type="ComboBox").Edit.SetText('C:\myfile.txt')
```